# How do you make multiple Post Api request and receive multiple responses using retrofit

Tags: kotlin, retrofit2, kotlin-coroutines

I want to make multiple Post request sending a list of data and would like to receive each response to check what was submitted successfully or not.

what is the best way to implement this? I tried the following code below

```
private suspend fun submitConfirmWeights(): Flow<Boolean> = flow {

        syncRepositoryImpl.getOfflineShopCollections().collect {
            it.forEach { weight ->
                val response = confirmWeightsService.confirmWeights(confirmWeightsDtoMapper.mapFromDomainModel(weight))
                if (response.isSuccessful && response.body()?.status == true){
                    emit(true)
                }else{
                    emit(false)
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: What did you try? What problem are you facing?

Comment: I've updated the post and I added the code, I'm trying to submit offline data so I want to check if each post request is successful or not. if true I want to return Result.success() in work manager, if false return Result.retry()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```kotlin
private suspend fun submitConfirmWeights(): Boolean {
    val collections = syncRepositoryImpl.getOfflineShopCollections().first() // get first emission
    return coroutineScope {
        collections.map { weight ->
            async { // get each response in parallel
                val response = confirmWeightsService.confirmWeights(confirmWeightsDtoMapper.mapFromDomainModel(weight))
                response.isSuccessful && response.body()?.status == true
            }
        }
            .awaitAll()  // wait for all the response
            .all { it }  // check that all are true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're basically converting `Flow<Iterable<T>>` to `Flow<Boolean>` your converting function doesn't have to be `suspend` at all.

```
private fun getConfirmedWeightsFlow() = syncRepositoryImpl.getOfflineShopCollections().map { collection ->
    coroutineScope {
        collection.map { entry ->
            async {
                val response = confirmWeightsService.confirmWeights(confirmWeightsDtoMapper.mapFromDomainModel(entry))
                response.isSuccessful && response.body()?.status == true
            }
        }
            .awaitAll()
            .all { successful -> successful }
    }
}
```

And then you can collect from this flow. Everytime a new collection is emitted it would be mapped through newly made requests' statuses to a `Boolean` value.